# python made windows service, cannot stop uninstall start

Tags: python, pywin32

I wrote a windows service following a short example with pywin32. I then run `python myfilename.py install` to register it into service list. Everything goes fine, and this short program update my data every day following the rule I give it.

But now, I want stop it to move the code file to another folder. And I run `python myfilename.py uninstall` , it reports error in prompt line.

```
Error Installing/removing/starting... Service:access denied (5)
```

How can I make this straight?

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks to fredtantini's re-edit.

Though I still don't konw why this problem occur, but I finally delete the service I created.
Use the command of "sc", start prompt line with administrator role, and type:
sc delete servicename

then restart computer
then this service will no longer in your service list